# Angular Route in Sub Directory issue in Firebase

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to build angular 7 basic app where the output directory is dist/oe2020 where all public file are created. I also have baseUrl set in my index.html like:

```
baseUrl="/oe2020/"
```

When I load the app it loads with index page. But I also have a route with home component which is set in app.routing.module.ts file like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path: 'home',
  component: HomeComponent,
 },
];
```

If you remove  /home then it shows the index page but you have /home route then its trying looks for index.html in home directory. 
But amazingly the same setup works fine when I have Hash integrated in route URL with providers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the answer. I have to setup rewrite in firebase.json like:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/oe2020/index.html"
  }
]
```